# Фразеологізм “не по зубах” - питомий чи калька з російської?

Tags: росіянізм, фразеологізми

Виникло питання, оскільки часто чую його, але щось мені ріже він вухо. [“Загуглила”](https://www.google.com.ua/search?rlz=1C1AWFC_enUA812UA812&ei=xq2OW867NMWPsAGAhb_wBA&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85+%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC&oq=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i71k1l2.0.0.0.8594.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.JOj4-7HY-uk) і вибило практично усі російськомовні посилання, серед яких і [Русские фразеологизмы](http://frazbook.ru/2011/06/11/ne-po-zubam/) , а також і [Тлумачний словник Єфремової](https://www.efremova.info/word/ne_po_zubam.html#.W46k_14zbIU).
Отож цікавить, чи фразеологізм “не по зубах” справді калька з російської, чи є питомим?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Згідно до [Словника українських фразеологізмів](http://schoolplusnet.com/up_portfolio/2016-3-2-21-42-22_file_20.pdf), "не по зубах" і справді є в нашій мові (сторінка 59).

Дивно, але на [цьому сайті](https://dovidka.biz.ua/frazeologizmi-zi-slovom-zub/) я не знайшов даного фразеологізму, однак,  нема його і серед запозичених (джерело [1](http://www.subject.com.ua/ukrmova/phraseology/30.html), [2](http://frazbook.ru/2011/06/11/ne-po-zubam/), [3](http://svitslova.com/mova/leksykologiya-frazeologiya/1919-jerela-frazeologizmiv.html)), тому гадаю, що фразеологізм "не по зубах" можна вживати в українській мові.

Answer (score 3):

Цей фразеологізм знаходимо без будь-яких позначок у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/zub) у словниковій статті *зуб*:

> Не по зубах кому, чиїх — не під силу кому-небудь.

Оскільки, слово **зуб** є спільним для всіх слов’янських мов  [Етимологічний словник т. 2 с. 281](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm), тому і фразеологізм пов’язаний з цим словом не є скалькований з російської.
Також цей фразеологізм знаходимо в [Українському фразеологічному словнику](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85&table=uk_fraz):

> **не по зубах кому**, чиїх.
>   Не під силу кому-небудь; який перевищує чиї-небудь фізичні або духовні можливості; надмірно важкий.

Отже, цей фразеологізм не є скалькованим з російської.